# domain validation issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design

Just a question, if i am using asp.net mvc as front end for my ddd application, then if i want validation in my domain entities, can i use asp.net mvc validation attribute for that ?

Because i was thinking that our domain should not tied to any specific programming language, so is using mvc validation attribute is awkward .

If i use mvc validation attribute than it will help me to do validation effectively, than writing custom .

Please help me in choosing an correct approach for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use validation attributes on your view models, but not on your domain models.

I've written why in another answer (which I know that you've found, but others might be interested): https://stackoverflow.com/a/9765945/70386

Most mappers (like Automapper) work without public properties, so you could validate the view model and then copy over the information to the domain model.

The problem with that solution is that your domain events (and more complex validation logic inside your domain model methods) will probably not be triggered.

Domain models forces you to design your UI after the domain (since CRUD applications don't work very well with domain models). It can feel a bit awkward in the start, but the user experience will be so much higher.

Comment: Agreed, but depending on the size and scale of the application he might choose to integrate his technology stack into his domain anyway. This wouldn't be the _purest_ DDD solution but might be a better fit for him (even though I fully agree with your answer otherwise).

Comment: @jqauffin   
thanks for your valuable answer, i have one more question, suppose i need validation like to see if the given email is already present in DB before registration, if yes then do not give error message or else persist it, where do i put this type of validation of checking in db like duplicate , email before persisting it

Answer (score 1):

An approach I often take is to use the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` attributes to validate ASP.NET MVC view model DTOs and then have the DTOs update or create domain objects accordingly. The domain objects validate themselves without validation attributes, using regular argument checks that throw `ArgumentException` instances instead. This allows the domain objects to always remain consistent, where as if you resort to a validation framework, you must be careful to execute the validation logic before entities are persisted (either by calling directly or intercepting ORM events). For example:

```
// this view model class lives in a Models folder in the ASP.NET MVC project
public class PersonViewModel
{
  [Required]  
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
  public string Email { get; set; }

  public Person ToPerson()
  {
    return new Person(this.Name, this.Email);
  }

  public void UpdatePerson(Person person)
  {
    person.Name = this.Name;
    person.Email = this.Email;
  }
}

// this domain class normally lives in the domain layer project
public class Person
{
  public Person(string name, string email = null)
  {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Email = email;
  }

  string name;
  string email;

  public string Name
  {
    get { return this.name; }
    set 
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) 
          throw new ArgumentException();
        this.name = value;
    }
  }

  public string Email
  {
    get { return this.email; }
    set 
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && !IsValidEmail(value))
          throw new ArgumentException();        
        this.email = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you can choose to use the validation attributes in `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` without using ASP.NET MVC. It is a separate assembly.

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, i have one more question, suppose i need validation like to see if the given email is already present in DB before registration, if yes then do not give error message or else persist it, where do i put this type of validation of checking in db like duplicate , email before persisting it.

Comment: That validation logic cannot be performed by the domain class itself since it doesn't and shouldn't have access to the repository of email addresses. Instead, that validation should be placed in the service which orchestrates operations on the domain. The service would have a reference to the repository which loads the domain entity by ID, as well as a repository which can verify email address uniqueness. This service can then be referenced by the MVC controller. The service abstraction isn't strictly necessary and you can just place all the orchestration code directly in the controller.

Comment: Do you mean put validations in domain service and inject repository in it ? can you provide some code, or any line from other websites. It would be great helpful to me in understanding.